# The page that opens vs The page that is opened

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

On a website I have an input field "Page" with a label / description below it: which one of the following is correct? If both are correct, is there any difference in meaning?

- The page that **is opened** when a user clicks the notification
- The page that **opens** when a user clicks the notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The files are "ready to download" or "ready to be downloaded"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78336/the-files-are-ready-to-download-or-ready-to-be-downloaded) Here, 'is opened' shows the passive usage while 'opens' shows the middle usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So are they both correct? Is it just a matter of preference? I am not a native english speaker and I simply want to avoid errors...

Comment: Your examples are both impeccable. One hints strongly at an agent (non-sentient, part of the program) magically doing the opening, while the other is totally matter-of-fact, but neither is less appropriate. With a human agent, compare 'The door was opened' vs 'The door opened'. Both fine. // Not all verbs behave like this.  'Children bruise easily' is idiomatic but not 'men wound easily'.

Comment: 'The page is opened...' leads one to think of the agent, unlike "The page opens..." which sounds better (to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are perfectly fine English sentences, and they mean the same thing. Some people may detect some hint of a subtle difference in emphasis, but I doubt it could ever make a difference.

Having said that, [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=page+that+is+opened+when%2Cpage+that+opens+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpage%20that%20opens%20when%3B%2Cc0) finds no hits at all of *page that is opened when,* while it does find at least some hits for *page that opens when.* Also interesting is that this phrase, too, is being used less and less after peaking about ten years ago.

[image]

At the same time, if you search google books, you find hits for both phrases in the published literature written by native speakers. But it is true that hits for *page that opens when* are more numerous.

*This is **the page that is opened when** the user clicks the Continue button that appears on the process-completed step.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/ASP_NET_2_For_Dummies/2gdKvFPATIoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20is%20opened%20when%22&pg=PA343&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22page%20that%20is%20opened%20when%22)
***The page that is opened when** a hyperlink is clicked…* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_Perspectives_on_the_Internet_Compreh/we8JAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20is%20opened%20when%22&pg=PR12&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22page%20that%20is%20opened%22)

*“Home page” also applies to **the main page that opens when** you first go to a Web site.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Microsoft_Office_2013_Illustrated_Introd/4zrZAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22that%20opens%20when%22)
*Most Web browsers have **a “home page” that opens when** the program is begun or when the navigation button is pressed.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Internet_for_Physicians/RU8IBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22that%20opens%20when%22)
*Click Home to return to **the web page that opens when** you open Safari.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Macs_All_in_One_For_Dummies/FddjAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22&pg=PA202&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22that%20opens%20when%22)
*Close **the blank page that opens when** you start Expression Web.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Microsoft_Expression_Web_2_On_Demand/-2z1Kmou8W8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22)
*Your landing page (as it's known in advertising) is **the page that opens when** users click your ad.* [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Facebook_Marketing_For_Dummies/jJPVBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22page%20that%20opens%20when%22)